# My django is no longer working because of the algorithm version not specified

Tags: python, django

I'm practicing creating a RESTAPI for ML model deployment[From this site](https://www.deploymachinelearning.com/compute-predictions/). By repeating the various processes such as data migration and testing. I feel like I'm duplicating things. I even had to change the owner and relaunch the codes. I see that new endpoints, MLagorithm, MLalgorithmstatus are created instead of the old ones being overwritten (which is what I expected)

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "random forest",
        "description": "Random Forest with simple pre- and post-processing",
        "code": "class RandomForestClassifier:\n    def __init__(self):\n        path_to_artifacts = \"../../research/\"\n        self.values_fill_missing =  joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"train_mode.joblib\")\n        self.encoders = joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"encoders.joblib\")\n        self.model = joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"random_forest.joblib\")\n\n    def preprocessing(self, input_data):\n        # JSON to pandas DataFrame\n        input_data = pd.DataFrame(input_data, index=[0])\n        # fill missing values\n        input_data.fillna(self.values_fill_missing)\n        # convert categoricals\n        for column in [\n            \"workclass\",\n            \"education\",\n            \"marital-status\",\n            \"occupation\",\n            \"relationship\",\n            \"race\",\n            \"sex\",\n            \"native-country\",\n        ]:\n            categorical_convert = self.encoders[column]\n            input_data[column] = categorical_convert.transform(input_data[column])\n\n        return input_data\n\n    def predict(self, input_data):\n        return self.model.predict_proba(input_data)\n\n    def postprocessing(self, input_data):\n        label = \"<=50K\"\n        if input_data[1] > 0.5:\n            label = \">50K\"\n        return {\"probability\": input_data[1], \"label\": label, \"status\": \"OK\"}\n\n    def compute_prediction(self, input_data):\n        try:\n            input_data = self.preprocessing(input_data)\n            prediction = self.predict(input_data)[0]  # only one sample\n            prediction = self.postprocessing(prediction)\n        except Exception as e:\n            return {\"status\": \"Error\", \"message\": str(e)}\n\n        return prediction\n",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "owner": "Piotr",
        "created_at": "2023-08-06T11:47:03.971558Z",
        "parent_endpoint": 1,
        "current_status": "production"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "random forest",
        "description": "Random Forest with simple pre- and post-processing",
        "code": "class RandomForestClassifier:\n    def __init__(self):\n        path_to_artifacts = \"../../research/\" # Definition of the path\n        self.values_fill_missing =  joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"train_mode.joblib\")\n        self.encoders = joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"encoders.joblib\")\n        self.model = joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"random_forest.joblib\")\n\n    def preprocessing(self, input_data):\n        # JSON to pandas DataFrame\n        input_data = pd.DataFrame(input_data, index=[0])\n        # fill missing values\n        input_data.fillna(self.values_fill_missing)\n        # convert categoricals\n        for column in [\"workclass\",\"education\",\"marital-status\",\"occupation\",\"relationship\",\n            \"race\", \"sex\",\"native-country\",]:\n             categorical_convert = self.encoders[column]\n             input_data[column] = categorical_convert.transform(input_data[column])\n             return input_data\n\n    def predict(self, input_data):\n        return self.model.predict_proba(input_data)\n\n    def postprocessing(self, input_data):\n        label = \"<=50K\"\n        if input_data[1] > 0.5:\n            label = \">50K\"\n        return {\"probability\": input_data[1], \"label\": label, \"status\": \"OK\"}\n\n    def compute_prediction(self, input_data):\n        try:\n            input_data = self.preprocessing(input_data)\n            prediction = self.predict(input_data)[0]  # only one sample\n            prediction = self.postprocessing(prediction)\n        except Exception as e:\n            return {\"status\": \"Error\", \"message\": str(e)}\n\n        return prediction\n",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "owner": "Piotr",
        "created_at": "2023-08-06T21:55:50.809051Z",
        "parent_endpoint": 1,
        "current_status": "production"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "random forest",
        "description": "Random Forest with simple pre- and post-processing",
        "code": "class RandomForestClassifier:\n    def __init__(self):\n        path_to_artifacts = \"../../research/\" # Definition of the path\n        self.values_fill_missing =  joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"train_mode.joblib\")\n        self.encoders = joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"encoders.joblib\")\n        self.model = joblib.load(path_to_artifacts + \"random_forest.joblib\")\n\n    def preprocessing(self, input_data):\n        # JSON to pandas DataFrame\n        input_data = pd.DataFrame(input_data, index=[0])\n        # fill missing values\n        input_data.fillna(self.values_fill_missing)\n        # convert categoricals\n        for column in [\"workclass\",\"education\",\"marital-status\",\"occupation\",\"relationship\",\n            \"race\", \"sex\",\"native-country\",]:\n             categorical_convert = self.encoders[column]\n             input_data[column] = categorical_convert.transform(input_data[column])\n             return input_data\n\n    def predict(self, input_data):\n        return self.model.predict_proba(input_data)\n\n    def postprocessing(self, input_data):\n        label = \"<=50K\"\n        if input_data[1] > 0.5:\n            label = \">50K\"\n        return {\"probability\": input_data[1], \"label\": label, \"status\": \"OK\"}\n\n    def compute_prediction(self, input_data):\n        try:\n            input_data = self.preprocessing(input_data)\n            prediction = self.predict(input_data)[0]  # only one sample\n            prediction = self.postprocessing(prediction)\n        except Exception as e:\n            return {\"status\": \"Error\", \"message\": str(e)}\n\n        return prediction\n",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "owner": "seydou",
        "created_at": "2023-08-15T19:46:18.044201Z",
        "parent_endpoint": 2,
        "current_status": "production"
    }
]
```

Now when I put the data in json format into the API for prediction:

```
{
    "age": 37,
    "workclass": "Private",
    "fnlwgt": 34146,
    "education": "HS-grad",
    "education-num": 9,
    "marital-status": "Married-civ-spouse",
    "occupation": "Craft-repair",
    "relationship": "Husband",
    "race": "White",
    "sex": "Male",
    "capital-gain": 0,
    "capital-loss": 0,
    "hours-per-week": 68,
    "native-country": "United-States"
}
```

I get this error message whereas before it worked fine.
[image]

I wonder if it's because I duplicated MLalgorithm twice.